# google cloud datastoreにおけるtruncate

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud

GoogleCloudDatastoreにおいて
データが大量に入っているとあるテーブル(kind)を削除したいと思っておりますが
delete()やdeleteMulti()を使うと速度的な懸念があるとともに
deleteのoperation数も大量に発生するのでGCPへの課金も発生するかと思います。

他のデータベースにあるようにとあるKindのデータをすべてtruncateできるような方法はdatastoreにありますでしょうか？

Comment: 自己回答ができないのでコメント欄に記載しますが。truncateは出来ないそうです。https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48108559/how-to-truncate-tablekind-in-datastore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

いいえ、Datastoreにはtruncateの機能はないので、KindのEntityをすべて削除する場合はDeleteOpesが発生します。

KindのEntityをすべて削除する場合は https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/console/datastore-backing-up-restoring を利用すると楽です。
ドキュメントにはbackupとrestoreのことが書いてありますが、deleteの機能もあります。